# Spring security with Task queue issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

In GAE I have cron job which looks up a table of emails and start sending those emails via push queue worker per each email.

```
// Worker method body
MailService m = MailServiceFactory.getMailService();
m.sendToAdmins(new MailService.Message(fromAddress, "", subject, content));
```

First I want to ask about sending emails, I've read in GAE documents that sending emails is queued job:

> The mail service queues the message, then attempts to send it,
>   possibly retrying if the destination mail server is unavailable.
>   Errors and bounce messages are sent to the sender address for the
>   email message.

If the previous is working same way as queue does this give me the option to just not use push queue ?

But Still I want to use Push queue for any future functionality so Here's The main problem:
Out team leader did the security part using spring security and tasks aren't working. And output per each task:

```
Dec 12, 2012 8:44:2 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.AppEngineAuthentication$AppEngineAuthenticator authenticate
INFO: Returning NOBODY because of SkipAdminCheck.
```

Please note that when I commented the following they did work just fine:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filterclass>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So what do you think is the reason for this ? is there a way to make task queue work without compromising security ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with a co-worker by adding the following to spring-security.xml (spring security layer)

```
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
<intercept-url pattern="/queuecontroller/**" access="permitAll" />
```

and adding constraint around it in web.xml (app engine security layer)

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>any-resource</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/emailcontroller</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```